# Extending SELECT projection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to extend the documents that I receive from a `SELECT` clause.

Lets assume a I have a collection that stores documents in the following shape

```
{"foo": "yeah I am a foo", "bar": "And I am a bar"}
```

so that the query

```
SELECT * FROM f
```

would return the above document(s)

Now I want to add an additional property that is NOT part of the documents stored as part of the projection of the `SELECT` statement.

Basically I'd like to do something like using Javascript's spread operator (which is not possible in Cosmos DB)

```
SELECT {...*, "newprop": "oh! I am new here!"} FROM f
```

and which should then return document(s) like this

```
{"foo": "yeah I am a foo", "bar": "And I am a bar", "newprop": "oh! I am new here!"}
```

The one thing I DONT WANT TO DO is to repeat all the toplevel properties of my documents. So a solution in the form of

```
SELECT {"foo": f.foo, "bar":f.bar, "newprop": "oh! I am new here!"} FROM f
```

is not desired.

I also tried to get that done via a function. Which I was not able to do as I cant find out how to get the toplevel object / document handle within the `SELECT` clause.
I tried the following

```
SELECT udf.ExtendDocument(*) FROM f
SELECT udf.ExtendDocument($1) FROM f
SELECT udf.ExtendDocument(f) FROM f
SELECT udf.ExtendDocument(value) FROM f
```

most of which produced a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use SELECT *, then append columns to the projection.

One option you could explore is to add a static property and value to the class that you deserialize your data into.

For instance, you could create a class like this simple one for a person with a hardcoded property and default value. Then deserialize your query results into it with the static value added as another property with a default value.

```
    class Person
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pk")]
        public string Pk { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string MyStaticColumn get; set; } = "Default Value";
    }
```

Then the code to run the query...

```
    public static async Task QueryPerson(Container container)
    {
        QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition("select * from c");

        FeedIterator<Person> resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Person>(
            query, requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
            {
                MaxConcurrency = -1
            });

        List<Person> results = new List<Person>();
        while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<Person> response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach(var p in response)
            {
                results.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution.

A) Build a user defined function that does the "Extension"

```
function extendProjection(x) {
    var result = {
        //usually one want to extend the returned doc
        //with some new calculated properties and not
        //with a static value
        newprop: calculateNewPropFromObject(x)
    }
    return Object.assign(result, x)
}
```

B) Use the user defined function in your `SELECT`

```
SELECT VALUE udf.extendProjection(c) FROM c

//it is important to use the keyword "VALUE" eitherwise
//the resulting doc will look {$1: { //the extendedprojection }}
```

Having described that I would recommend against this approach

1. Your RUs will easily tripple. The reason seems to be the usage of the JS itself and not so much what the JS engine does.
2. its not possible to "reuse" different registered UDFs within your JS code.
   So one has to copy code snippets
3. "Extended Properties" are not useable in your `WHERE` clause
4. Runtime error messages returned from Cosmos DB are horrible to decipher.
   The lack of any decent development environment is basically a no go.

Comment: In addition to the high RU cost another issue is UDF's (along with sprocs and triggers in Cosmos) only run on the primary replica. This means they only have 1/4 of the total throughput provisioned on the collection. In high concurrency situations this is not ideal and requires provisioning more RU/s than you would need if not using UDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Like @mark-brown already answered, **it does not seem to be possible**.

I would just like to add that likely **you shouldn't do that anyway** and offer a workaround arguably better than the UDF (which is costly, hard-to-maintain, does not support multiple concurrent logic versions, etc).

If you want to add extra calculations to query output based on the same entire document, then it would make more sense to **do it in business layer (after querying), not data layer (CosmsosDB queries)**. It would also be faster (less calculations, less data to move) and cheaper (less RU).

If you want to add static data (ex: a fix string or other constants), then the same argument applies - passing it back-and-forth to cosmosDB just makes things  slower and costlier. **That's not the responsibility of storage**.

##### The workaround

If the goal is to query an entire CHILD object and add only a few selected properties from other areas of documents then its best not to try to flatten the object. Just **keep your storage model objects and extras side-by-side**, ex:

```
select c.childWithAllTheFutureChildren,
    c.other.location.single.value as newProp
from c
```

If you really-really want to add some calculation/statics to query output then you could also still use the same pattern for entire document:

```
SELECT c as TheRealStoredThing,
    'oh! I am new here!' as theNewProp
FROM c
```

Yes, it does require you to have a separate model on client side for this query, but that's a good clean practice anyway. And it's much simpler than using/maintaining UDFs.